# rsync daemon without rsyncd.conf

Tags: rsync

Will rsyncd run without its config file (rsyncd.conf) ? 
What is its behavior if run this way?

Backstory:
So, I'm using rsync to backup user directories from (call it) server A, and it's working nicely, so I decide to do the same with server B.  Server B doesn't have rsync installed, so I find a package and install it.  It doesn't work out of the box, so I have to do some configuring.  It's mostly all about rsyncd.conf, so I have a look on server A and...it's not there.  As in "find / -name ..." not there.  Server A is running CentOS 6.  Server A lets me back up any user I call for, but Server B refuses to do any of that, so I was forced to set up the config file, with modules pointing at the directories I wanted to back up.  I had to grind through the details myself.

rsyncd is being run via xinetd, and I checked /etc/xinetd.d/rsync for any command options and there's nothing besides --daemon.

But none of the documentation mentions what I get if the config file is absent.  I'd expect a statement as to what it would do by default.

Comment: Did you execute find as root/sudo? It's usually just /etc/rsyncd.conf.